# Will moving contents of git clone break git?

Tags: git, clone

I created a clone of a git repo using the `git clone` command. It created a directory `/home/xyz` in which the `src` folder exists.
But I want it to be cloned to an existing directory, `/home/root/xyz`.

It's not creating a clone into `/home/root/xyz` as it has some other files and folders in it along with src.

My question is...Suppose I create a clone at `/home/xyz` and move all the contents of `/home/xyz`, will it break git? Will it create problems when checking out and in ?

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to either move the directory itself, or else to move all of the contents.

If you're moving the contents, make sure you include the ".git" directory and any other git related files such as ".gitignore".

Answer (score 1):

Are the current files you have in the folder overlapping with the files of the repo, filenames, paths, etc.?
If no, then there shouldn't be any issues for you to have them in the same folder, git only cares about the files you have tracked, eg. run "git add " on and when you change branches etc it will ignore untracked files

Comment: Some post suggest the following steps. What do they do ?  $ git init  
$ git remote add origin your-git-url  
$ git fetch  
$ git reset --mixed origin/master